# React: How to insert a object inline of a JSX tag?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-hook-form

hoping this is simple / possible.

I am using React & React Hooks Form.

React Hooks Form requires a JSX tag similar to this to mark a input as required:

```
<input {...register(`${fieldName}`, { required: true })}/>
```

Now since not every input needs to be required, I'm wondering how to dynamically insert that object inline into the  tag.

I tried the following and did not have any success:

```
 const formulateRegisterObject = (fieldName, requiredBool) => {
        switch(requiredBool){
            case true:
                return {...register(`${fieldName}`, { required: true })}
            case false:
                return {...register(`${fieldName}`)}
        }
    }


    const getInput = (inputObj) => {
        const requiredProp = formulateRegisterObject(inputObj.input_type, inputObj.required)
        switch(inputObj.input_type){
            case "text-type":
                return (
                    <div className="fieldRow">
                        <input id={`${inputObj.input_type}id`} type="text" requiredProp/>
                    </div>
                );
        }
    }
```

I also tried directly in line like the following:

```
<input id={`${inputObj.input_type}id`} type="text" {requiredProp}/>

-or-
<input id={`${inputObj.input_type}id`} type="text" {formulateRegisterObject("cat", true)}/>


-or-

<input id={`${inputObj.input_type}id`} type="text"<input {...register(`${fieldName}`, formulateRegisterObject("cat", true))}/>
```

But neither worked. I'm guessing i'm missing something obvious here but hoping someone can help!

I could just do a ternary expression before the  field and do it that way, but was hoping for something less DRY

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX doesn't allow for expressions to be directly inside of tags the way you're attempting.

using your `formulateRegisterObject` function to determine the props:

```
const formulateRegisterObject = (fieldName, requiredBool) => {
  if (requiredBool) {
    return {...register(fieldName, { required: true })}
  }
  return {...register(fieldName)};
}
```

spread the object returned by `formulateRegisterObject` directly into your JSX

```
const getInput = (inputObj) => {
    const requiredProp = formulateRegisterObject(inputObj.input_type, inputObj.required);
    switch(inputObj.input_type){
        case "text-type":
            return (
                <div className="fieldRow">
                    <input id={`${inputObj.input_type}id`} type="text" {...requiredProp}/>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew it was something simple :(  Thanks bro. 

Since i'm spreading the requiredProp, should I remove the spread from the formulateRegisterObject? 

Thanks!

Comment: Or just `return {...register(fieldName, { required: requiredBool })};`.

Comment: This is getting me closer! For some reason the "required" part isn't passing (must be a react hook forms issue?) but this is already great help. thank you both